# Is casein a better choice for people with limited recovery ability?

Tags: strength-training, protein, muscle-recovery, protein-shakes, muscle-gain

My body takes several days to recover after each full-body workout. Several things may play a role on this fact (lack of abundant sleep, mid-age, whatever) but in any case it is very noticeable and I sort of accepted it already (there is progress after all).

I am sure whey protein with its fast absorption rate is a great friend of young american-football players full of growth hormone, testosterone and acne. Whey is supposed to release amino acids into the bloodstream faster than any other thing, feeding their efficient recovery abilities.

But, since my muscle repair takes place more slowly, I think I need something quite at the opposite end of the absorption rate spectrum, providing me with a lower but more steady supply of amino acids. If I take whey, it will mostly be excreted as urine and/or converted into fat tissue, not to mention the burden on my liver and kidneys, all for nothing.

Is that right? I have been taking 20-something grams of casein at night during ~10 days now and I might be wrong, but I think it is having a positive impact in my recovery. Muscle soreness disappears faster than usual, and lately I haven't had any joint discomfort (which usually happen in either joint or the other the day after each workout).

I had experienced before with white egg powder, but I didn't notice any change. It is too soon to tell with accuracy, but I have the impression that casein is having a positive impact on my recovery times (remark: the rest of the day I eat natural foods). Not much on the load or volume progress, but on the recovery ability.

Comment: It's anecdotal, but in a basic sense if you've found something that's working better for you, rock it.

Comment: There's a lot of talk about protein timing and such, but afaik, the only scientifically based fact is that eating more protein per day leads to more hypertrophy. Some people do intermittent fasting, which means they only have a very small window for absorbing protein, and they can still get huge.

Comment: I also introduced more saturated fats, mainly by abandoning low fat milk and taking 2% or even whole fat milk instead.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend taking some casein before sleep if your recovery time is high. [This study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22330017) shows that casein metabolism and absorbtion is pretty high during sleep, which stimulates muscle recovery at a higher rate.

I discovered this study a few months ago, and tried it out to surprisingly good effect. Naturally, this is anecdotal for my own experience, but since my experience was aligned with the result of the study, I feel confident in recommending it.